# React Native - Save Video to Camera Roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I'm downloading video files to application documents directory and i need to copy my downloaded videos to camera roll. How can i do this with react native?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like the CameraRoll API is good for pictures, but not as good for videos https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll

Comment: I answered this question on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258483/save-video-to-cameraroll-react-native/58713657#58713657

Answer (score 0):

The CameraRoll API would be the place to have a look at, maybe the [saveimagewithtag](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/cameraroll.html#saveimagewithtag) method works for you. Otherwise, there is no built-in possibility and you would have to implement it on your own.