# Save Video to CameraRoll React-Native

Tags: download, react-native, camera-roll

It´s possible to save a video on React-Native using cameraRoll, for images with saveImageWithTag() it´s easy but i can´t found documentation for videos.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to save a video to CameraRoll, I did it with the following line of code.

```
 saveVideoToCameraRoll = async (uri) => {
await CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(uri, 'video')
}
```

NB: Obviously this function expects a `uri or filePath` of your video.